# How to use an equality condition for manipulating a Pandas Dataframe based on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Python, say `A`, which has multiple columns, including columns named `ECode` and `FG`. I have another Pandas dataframe `B`, also with multiple columns, including columns named `ECode`,`F Gping` (note the space in column name for `F Gping`) and `EDesc`. What I would like to do is to create a new column called `EDesc` in dataframe A based on following conditions (Note that `EDesc`, `FG` and `F Gping` contain `String` type values (text), while the remaining columns are numeric/floating type. Also, dataframes `A` and `B` are of different dimensions (with differing rows and columns, and I want to check equality in specific values in the dataframe columns):-

1. First, for all rows in dataframe `A`, where value in `ECode` matches value `ECode` in dataframe `B`, then, in the new column `EDesc` to be created in dataframe `A`, add the same values as `EDesc` in `B`.
2. Secondly, for all rows in dataframe `A` where value in `FG` matches `F Gping` values, in the new column `EDesc` in `A`, add same values as `EDesc` in `B`.
3. After this, if the newly created `EDesc` column in `A` still has missing values/NaNs, then add the string value `MissingValue` to all the rows in the Dataframe `A`'s `EDesc` column.

I have tried using `for` loops, as well as list comprehensions, but they don't help in accomplishing this. Moreover, the space within column name `F Gping` in `B` is created problems to access the same, as though I can access it like `B['F Gping']`, it isn't solving the very purpose. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming values are unique in B['ECode'] and B['F Gping'], otherwise we'll have to choose which value we give to A['EDesc'] when we find two matching values for ECode or FG.

There might be a smarter way but here's what I would do with joins:

Example DataFrames:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'ECode': [1, 1, 3, 4, 6],
                  'FG': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'y']})
B = pd.DataFrame({'ECode': [1, 2, 3, 5],
                  'F Gping': ['b', 'c', 'x', 'x'],
                  'EDesc': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
```

So they look like:

```
A
   ECode FG
0      1  a
1      1  b
2      3  c
3      4  b
4      6  y

B
   ECode F Gping EDesc
0      1       b     a
1      2       c     b
2      3       x     c
3      5       x     d
```

First let's create A['EDesc'] by saying that it's the result of joining A and B on ECode. We'll temporarily use EDesc as index:

```
A.set_index('ECode', inplace=True, drop=False)
B.set_index('ECode', inplace=True, drop=False)

A['EDesc'] = A.join(B, lsuffix='A')['EDesc']
```

This works because the result of A.join(B, lsuffix='A') is:

```
       ECodeA FG  ECode F Gping EDesc
ECode                                
1           1  a    1.0       b     a
1           1  b    1.0       b     a
3           3  c    3.0       x     c
4           4  b    NaN     NaN   NaN
6           6  y    NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Now let's fillna on A['EDesc'], using the match on FG. Same thing:

```
A.set_index('FG', inplace=True, drop=False)
B.set_index('F Gping', inplace=True, drop=False)

A['EDesc'].fillna(A.join(B, lsuffix='A')['EDesc'].drop_duplicates(), inplace=True)
```

This works because the result of A.join(B, lsuffix='A') is:

```
   ECodeA FG EDescA  ECode F Gping EDesc
a       1  a      a    NaN     NaN   NaN
b       1  b      a    1.0       b     a
b       4  b    NaN    1.0       b     a
c       3  c      c    2.0       c     b
y       6  y    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Also we dropped the duplicates because as you can see there are two b's in our index.

Finally let's fillna with "Missing" and reset the index:

```
A['EDesc'].fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
A.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```